# change value in object from 1 to true

Tags: ios, format-specifiers

I have an object that contains the value 1 or 0 for true or false.  For example, let's call my object Stuff and stuff has look like this.

```
@interface Stuff : NSObject {

NSString *_boolValue1;
NSString *_boolValue2;
}
```

When I populate my entity with values, for example: Stuff *stuff = [[Stuff alloc] init...] if I used NSLog to display the values stored in boolValue1 and boolValue2 they might output a 1 or a 0.  I would like to use NSLog to output something like [stuff.boolValue1 == 1 ? @"true" : @"false"].  What am I missing?  I am getting an error that the format specifies type 'id' but the argument has type 'BOOL'...

```
NSString *myStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [stuff.boolValue1 isEqualToString:@"1" ? @"true" : @"false"]];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You bracket is just in the wrong place, as the isEqualToString operator returns the bool.

```
NSString *myStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [stuff.boolValue1 isEqualToString:@"1"] ? @"true" : @"false"];
```

or, the simpler, more typical way, using suggestion from the comments below:

```
NSString *myStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [stuff.boolValue1 boolValue] ? @"true" : @"false"];
```

Comment: Why not use `intValue`, or even `boolValue`

Comment: Sure, that would work.  I was just addressing OP's question directly as to what was wrong with his statement.

Comment: @brianhevans Hmm, check your code elsewhere for the error, I just ran it successfully as written.

Comment: Edited answer to reflect @RichardJ.RossIII 's suggestions.

Comment: Ok thanks.  I commented out the line of code you suggested and it builds so I am not sure why I am getting 'Expected identifier'...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17623/discussion-between-diatrevolo-and-brianhevans)